# Java - Modificar un JTable por medio de un Jframe externo

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, jtable

Buenas, tengo una duda con respecto a un **JTable**.
El programa funciona guardando datos de un producto y luego los lista, pero al querer modificar por medio de un **JFrame** externo(que aparece al presionar el botón EDITAR) no logro modificar esos datos del **JTable** ya mencionado, queria saber que codigo deberia ingresar al **JFrame** "Editar" (Adjunto codigo) para poder actualizar en en **JTable**. Gracias

[image: DatosProductos]

[image: Listar]

[image: Editar]

```
private void grabar() {

    producto = new Producto();
    producto.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
    producto.setCantidad(Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText()));
    producto.setPrecio(Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio.getText()));
    model.RegistrarProducto(producto);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos Registrados");
    listar();
}

public void listar() {

    DefaultTableModel tabla = (DefaultTableModel) this.tblProductos.getModel();
    Object[] fila = {producto.getNombre(), producto.getCantidad(), producto.getPrecio()};
    tabla.addRow(fila);
}
 private void editar() {

    ProductoEditar edita = new ProductoEditar();
    edita.setVisible(true);
    int seleccionar = this.tblProductos.getSelectedRow();
    if (seleccionar >= 0) {
        Object[] filaselect = {
            this.tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 0),
            this.tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 1),
            this.tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 2)};
        ProductoEditar.txtNombreEditar.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[0]));
        ProductoEditar.txtCantidadEditar.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[1]));
        ProductoEditar.txtPrecioEditar.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[2]));
    }
```

CODIGO EDITAR

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           



}
```

Comment: Me parecieron buenisimas esas ventanas, como las hiciste? Color, botones, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entiendo que quieres hacer es que al darle guardar el JFrame editar me liste nuevamente los datos, pues lo único que debes hacer es que al dar clic

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    guardatoseditados();//Por ejemplo método que realiza la modificación de los datos                                           
    this.dispose(); //Cerrar JFrame
    classJTable listTable = new classJTable();
    listTable.listar(); //volver a listar los datos
}
```

Y listo ..